# PHP Array in SESSION with $_POST content

Tags: php, session

I've got a from, with 2 information from 2 field.
Everytime you submit the form you came to another page where I want to display them in an array.

What I did is:

```
$buchtyp = $_POST['buchtyp'];
$a_id_warenkorb = $_POST['a_id_warenkorb'];
$_SESSION['warenkorb'][$a_id_warenkorb] = $a_id_warenkorb;
```

If I show the content of this array, it failed.

Comment: what do you get when you do `var_dump($_POST);` before that?

Comment: is `$a_id_warenkorb` a non-negative integer?

Answer (score 0):

```
$buchtyp = $_POST['buchtyp'];
$_SESSION['buchtyp'][] = array($buchtyp);

$a_id_warenkorb = $_POST['a_id_warenkorb'];
$_SESSION['warenkorb'][] = array($a_id_warenkorb);
```

I changed it and now it works. Its not saved in one array, but its fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Try
`foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}`